# how to Use multiple different characters for quotechar in python csv reader

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file that sometimes uses double quotes (") for strings and sometimes uses single quotes (') for strings.

I would like to read the file to properly handle these strings.

It is not necessary but it would be helpful if " don't " was parsed correctly. This is why I want to avoid just replacing every ' for ".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` to prevent quote processing by `csv.reader`, then use `ast.literal_eval` to interpret values as Python literals (or, if that fails, keep them as strings).

```
import io
import csv
from ast import literal_eval

def unquote(item):
    item = item.strip()
    try:
        return literal_eval(item.strip())
    except ValueError:
        return item

f = io.StringIO(r'''
        bare, "John \"O'Brien\" Smith", 'John "O\'Brien" Smith', 42
        '''.strip())
reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

for row in reader:
    parsed_row = [unquote(item) for item in row]
    print(parsed_row)
    # => ['bare', 'John "O\'Brien" Smith', 'John "O\'Brien" Smith', 42]
```

Note though that since they are evaluated as Python literals, any unquoted field values that represent valid Python literals (e.g. `True` or `42`) will not remain as strings.

Answer (score 0):

A crude way to handle this would be to use `regex` to detect any single quotation which is either preceded by a space, or followed by a space.

We can then replace just these quotations with `"` and ignore the ones which have letters directly next to them.

---

**CSV**

```
"""Let's do a test""","""We will replace all 'single' quotation's not within""","""A word to """""
```

---

**Python**

```
import re
pattern = r'((?<=\s)\')|(\'(?=\s))'

data = []

with open('hello.csv', 'r') as file:
    for row in file.readlines():
        data.append(re.sub(pattern, '"', row))
```

---

**Output**

```
['"""Let\'s do a test""","""We will replace all "single" quotation\'s not within""","""A word to """""\n']
```